# BreezeJS modified route not working

Tags: asp.net, breeze

My application has two databases with exactly the same schema.  Basically, I need to change the DbContext based on what data I'm accessing. Two countries are in one Db and 4 countries in the other.  I want the client to decide which context is being used.  I tried changing my BreezeWebApiConfig file so that the route looks like this:

```
  GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "BreezeApi",
      routeTemplate: "breeze/{dbName}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new {id=RouteParameter.Optional,dbName="db1"}
  );
```

I added the string to the controller actions:

```
[HttpGet]
public string Metadata(string dbName="")
    {
        return _contextProvider.Metadata();
    }
```

And changed the entityManager service Name.

Now when the client spins up, it accesses the corrent metadata action and I get a message:

```
Error: Metadata query failed for: /breeze/clienthistory/kenya/Metadata. Unable to either parse or import metadata: Type .... already exists in this MetadataStore
```

When I go to the metadata url from the browser, I get the correct metadata (exactly the same as when I remove the {dbName} segment from the route).  If I remove the {dbName} segment from the route I get no error and everything works fine

(I have not started implementing the multiple contexts yet -- I am just trying to make the additional segment work).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your Breeze client is issuing two separate requests for the same metadata, once under each of the two "serviceNames". Breeze tries to blend them both into the same `EntityManager.metadataStore` ... and can't because that would mean duplication of `EntityType` names.

One approach that should work is to begin your application by fetching the metadata immediately upon app start and then adding all the associated "DataServiceNames" to the `MetadataStore`.

Try something along these lines (pseudo-code):

```
var manager;
var store = new breeze.MetadataStore();
return store.fetchMetadata(serviceName1)
    .then(gotMetadata)
    .catch(handleFail);

function gotMetadata() {
    // register the existing metadata with each of the other service names
    store.addDataService(new breeze.DataService(serviceName2));

    ... more services as needed ...

    manager = new breeze.EntityManager({
        dataService:   store.getDataService(serviceName1), // service to start
        metadataStore: store
    });

    return true; // return something
}
```

## Alternative

Other approaches to consider don't involve 'db' placeholder in the base URL nor any toying with the Web API routes. Let's assume you stay vanilla in that respect with your basic service name

```
var serviceName = '/breeze/clienthistory/';
..
```

For example, you could add an optional parameter to your routes (let's call it `db`) as needed via a [`withParameters` clause](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityQuery.html#method_withParameters).

Here is a query:

```
return new breeze.EntityQuery.from('Clients')
    .where(...)
    .withParameters({db: database1}); // database1 == 'kenya'
    .using(manager).execute()
    .then(success).catch(failed);
```

which produces a URL like:

```
/breeze/clienthistory/Clients/?$filter=...&db=kenya
```

It makes an implicit *first-time-only* metadata request that resolves to:

```
/breeze/clienthistory/Metadata
```

Your server-side Web API query methods can expect `db` as an optional parameter:

```
[HttpGet]
public string Metadata(string db="")
{
        ... do what is right ...
}
```

#### Saves?

I assume that you also want to identify the target database when you save. There are lots of ways you can include that in the save request

- in a custom HTTP header via [a custom AJAX adapter](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/controlling-ajax) (you could do this for queries too)
- in a query string parameter or hash segment on the `saveChanges` POST request URL (again via a custom AJAX adapter).
- in the `tag` property of the `saveOptions` object (easily accessed by the server implementation of `SaveChanges`)
- in the `resourceName` property of the `saveOptions` object (see "[named save](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/saving-changes)")

You'll want to explore this variety of options on your own to find the best choice for you.

Comment: Thanks @ward.  Extremely helpful, as always.  This gives me lots of options.  Thanks!